# Hadoop datanode services is not starting in the slaves in hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to configure hadoop-1.0.3 multinode cluster with one master and two slave in my laptop using vmware workstation.

when I ran the ***start-all.sh*** from master all daemon process running in master node (namenode,datanode,tasktracker,jobtracker,secondarynamenode) but Datanode and tasktracker is not starting on slave node. Password less ssh is enabled and I can do ssh for both master and slave from my masternode without pwd.

Please help me resolve this.

Comment: You should also include logs of the errors - check both master and the slave nodes. Logs are typically found under hadoopdir/logs

Answer (score 10):

Stop the cluster.

If you have specifically defined tmp directory location in `core-site.xml`, then remove all files under those directory.

If you have specifically defined data node and namenode directory in `hdfs-site.xml`, then delete all the files under those directories.

If you have not defined anything in `core-site.xml` or `hdfs-site.xml`, then please remove all the files under `/tmp/hadoop-*nameofyourhadoopuser`.

Format the namenode.

It should work!